# AjaxEditableLabel showing Date formatted by SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, wicket

I have and AjaxEditableLabel with shows a date from a Date object, but when its shown in its formated likes this "08-08-07 00:00". Is there something i can add to the label so it presents its object differently?

```
item.add(new AjaxEditableLabel("stockEntry_date")
{
@Override
public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    super.onEdit(target);
    //Save to database
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DateFormat class from java to get a string representation of the date in the format you want. You can use the DateFormat to convert your Date to a String for the displaying purpose and then convert it back to a Date for what you want to do with it (like saving to database)

It will probably look like this (please note that I did not use any IDE to write this code so it may not be correct)

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(desiredFormat);
myString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(myDate);

item.add(new AjaxEditableLabel("stockEntry_date", myString)
{
@Override
public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    super.onEdit(target);
    df.parse(this.getLabel().getDefaultModelObject());//not sur if this is the correct to get the label value
    //Save to database
    }
});
```